# AWS hosted site not running script when access with public IP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I've hosted my Angular app on AWS for the first time. Configure the domain, setup security groups. Currently it is only hosted on HTTP since there is no user or payment information being transferred from site. However when I try and access the site from a public IP it seems all javascript is broken and not running and hence only the html components on the page are running. Bit of a pain since most of the site is built with angular and the majority of the html is built via angular templating.

Any suggestion appreciated.

I've attached the screenshot of what I see when viewing from mobile (and seo analyzer site) and what I see when view from own pc using this address

[mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnxyY.jpg)

[fully function screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnxyY.jpg)

included the html for the mainpage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>

<html  ng-app="landingApp" >
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/bootstrap-custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/myStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/landing.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/demoApp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/animation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/searchFacets.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./presentationResources/css/jquery.bxslider.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./presentationResources/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/highlighter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/landing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/landingAboutUs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/landingMainAppDemoSupp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/landingMainAppDemo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./presentationResources/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<title>Personnel Tracker</title>
<style>



</style>

<script>



  $(document).ready(function(){

      document.getElementById("openByDefault").click();
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
       captions: true
      });

          var bxViewportHeight = $(".bx-viewport").height();
          console.log("height : "+bxViewportHeight);

          if(bxViewportHeight < 300){
              $(".carouselAndBuzzSection").css("margin-bottom", "20%");
          }else{
              $(".carouselAndBuzzSection").css("margin-bottom", "0%");
          }

    });


</script>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="title" content="Personnel Tracker 360" />
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="description" content="Personnel Tracker 360 by Scion Solutions Group empowers organisations to accurately track all aspects of employee management. Matching skillset to current roles and providing performance reporting. " />

</head>
<body>


 <div id="main-box" class="main-box responsive">

<h1 class="pageHeaderLogo responsive"> Personnel Tracker <span>360</span> </h1>
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks defaultTab glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"
    onclick="openTab(event, 'welcomeTab')" id="openByDefault" >
         <span style="font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif !important;">Welcome </span></a></li>

  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks glyphicon glyphicon-home" onclick="openTab(event, 'appTab')">
    <span style="font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif !important;"> Demo App</span></a></li>

  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" onclick="openTabAboutUs(event, 'aboutTab')">
   <span style="font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif !important;">About Us</span></a></li>
 <div class="_stickFigureElement responsive"><img class="imgAnime" src='./presentationResources/images/profilePics/stickfigure2.png' /></div>
</ul>




<div id="welcomeTab" class="tabcontent">
    <welcome-page></welcome-page>
</div>
<div id="appTab" class="tabcontent">
    <app-page-demo></app-page-demo>
</div>
<div id="aboutTab" class="tabcontent">
    <about-us-page></about-us-page>
</div>



 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't remotely reference any javascript.

Comment: Open the developer console and see network tab. Inform us any errors there.

Comment: It sounds like you need to open your browser's debugging console and see what the javascript errors are. Once you've gathered more information, if you still can't solve this then please update your question with the extra info. As it is there isn't enough detail here for anyone to help you.

Comment: How are you including js in your project? Are you serving with express? It sounds like whatever page you are serving doesn't have access to your js file/files.

Comment: I'm not using express but I don't reference any remote js libraries. I can see the page fine without any errors from this link but when viewing from mobile it isn't running any js. The link - http://www.personneltracker360.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

was actually caused by this IE11 issue and my templates were not showing up as a result which accounted for the majority of html on the website.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/234